# how to send live video over network in python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv

i'am trying to send video from client to server and showing it at the server side. the probleme is that when i run the code i get an empty non respond window !

here is the code i'am using which i have found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988516/4663461

client.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct 

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data))+data)
```

server.py

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct 

HOST=''
PORT=8089

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print ('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print ('Socket now listening')

conn,addr=s.accept()


data = b''
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") 
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]
    ###

    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
    print frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Comment: http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/

Comment: Here is the exact solution to your problem https://pyshine.com/Socket-Programming-with-multiple-clients/

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of late but I've created powerful & threaded [**VidGear**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library that now provides [**NetGear API**](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/netgear/overview/), which is exclusively designed to transfer video frames synchronously between interconnecting systems over the network in real-time through ZmQ messaging system. Here's a bare-minimum example for your convenience:

#### A. Server End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Open your favorite terminal and execute the following python code:

**Note:** *You can end streaming anytime on both server and client side by pressing [Ctrl+c] on your keyboard on server end!*

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from vidgear.gears import NetGear

stream = VideoGear(source='test.mp4').start() #Open any video stream
server = NetGear() #Define netgear server with default settings

# infinite loop until [Ctrl+C] is pressed
while True:
    try: 
        frame = stream.read()
        # read frames

        # check if frame is None
        if frame is None:
            #if True break the infinite loop
            break

        # do something with frame here

        # send frame to server
        server.send(frame)
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #break the infinite loop
        break

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()
# safely close server
writer.close()
```

#### B. Client End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Then open another terminal on the same system and execute the following python code and see the output:

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import NetGear
import cv2

#define netgear client with `receive_mode = True` and default settings
client = NetGear(receive_mode = True)

# infinite loop
while True:
    # receive frames from network
    frame = client.recv()

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break

    # do something with frame here

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# safely close client
client.close()
```

***Note:** NetGear currently supports only two ZeroMQ messaging patterns: i.e `zmq.PAIR`, `zmq.REQ and zmq.REP` and `zmq.PUB and zmq.SUB`, and the supported protocol are: `'tcp', 'ipc'`*

**More advanced usage can be found here:** https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/NetGear

Answer (score 0):

```
frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
print frame
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
# add this
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Comment: Provide some details also !